Why can't I change the MAC address?
I have Zte Blade A5 2019 with dynamic root GSI CaOS and I'm trying to change my MAC Address with:
su ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 11:22:33:44:55:66

It doesn't return an error, but MAC address doesn't change.
I also tried:
ip link set wlan0 11:22:33:44:55:66

But it returns:
either "dev" is duplicate, or "11:22:33:44:55:66" is a garbage

I received no result trying to change this in root explorer and using different software.
Finally I tried to remove this in root explorer and with:
rm /root/sys/class/net/wlan0/address

Which returns:
Can't remove "rm /root/sys/class/net/wlan0/address": permission denied

Edit: SOLVED, problem was in my kernel, I couldnt flash it so I just changed my phone with grandmother

11:22:33:44:55:66 is not a valid MAC address.
It's a multicast/broadcast address, not a unicast address.
It has the 1's-place bit of the first octet (8-bit byte) set. That bit is the broadcast/multicast bit. You can't use that as the MAC address of an Ethernet interface.
When setting a custom MAC address, you should always clear the 1's-place bit and set the 2's-place bit of the first octet.
The 2's-place bit signifies that it's a "locally administered" MAC address, meaning it wasn't factory assigned and thus isn't guaranteed to be globally unique; it was arbitrarily or randomly generated by someone else. That's why "MAC address privacy" features of modern mobile OSes always keep the 2's-place bit set when they generate random addresses; they're taking advantage of this old provision of the Ethernet MAC address scheme that allows anyone to create their own address as long as they flag it by setting the 2's-place bit of the first octet.
So try 12:22:33:44:55:66 or 12:34:56:78:90:AB or 02:03:04:05:06:07, etc.
But whatever you try, that second hex digit of the first octet needs to be 2, 6, A, or E, because those are the only hexadecimal values that, in binary, have the 2's-place bit set and the 1's-place bit cleared.

I up voted this because it was an interesting read - however I don't know that this will solve the OP's problem as there appears to be other limits in place as well. SELinux???

Thanks for your answer, but i still cant change this trying with any MAC address. dummy0(ethernet) is changing correctly. trying to 'ifconfig wlan0 down' and then change this returns 'ioctl 8924: no such device'
